# How to wire Angular2 + Webpack + Node + Express?

Tags: node.js, express, typescript, webpack

First of all, I have it wired and working, but I am somewhat discontent with the result and have a feeling it can be improved.

(The current result can be found here - https://github.com/MarkKharitonov/Angular2WebpackNodeExpress/tree/v0.0.1.)

The directory structure is:

```
C:.
│   .gitignore
│   package.json
│   tsconfig.json
│   tslint.json
│   typings.json
│   webpack.config.js
│
├───dist
│   └───server
│           api.js
│           api.js.map
│           main.js
│           main.js.map
│
└───src
    ├───client
    │       app.component.ts
    │       index.html
    │       main.ts
    │       polyfills.ts
    │       tsconfig.json
    │       vendor.ts
    │
    └───server
            api.ts
            main.ts
            tsconfig.json
```

Right now the `dist` folder has only the server side files compiled from `./src/server`. They are placed there by the IntelliJ IDEA, because `./src/server/tsconfig.json` requests compilation on save.

The client side bundling occurs in memory courtesy of webpack-dev-server. The `./src/client/tsconfig.json` **does not** request compilation on save.

The things I dislike about my current setup are described here - https://github.com/MarkKharitonov/Angular2WebpackNodeExpress/tree/v0.0.1#problems, namely:

1. webpack is going to take care of any plain .js files under **./src/client** - they would be bundled and placed under **./dist/client** automatically. But what about plain .js files under ./src/server ? Do I need a task runner for that (gulp, grunt, whatever ...) or is there a solution within webpack?
2. I have three tsconfig.json files - **./src/client/tsconfig.json**, **./src/server/tsconfig.json** and **./tsconfig.json**. The three files share most of the options, but not all. Right now I copy them in each of the three files - not very good.
3. In addition, because the **typings** folder is at the root I have to start all the top level TypeScript files (**.\src\client\main.ts**, **.\src\client\polyfills.ts**, **.\src\client\vendor.ts** and **.\src\server\main.ts**) with `/// <reference path="../../typings/index.d.ts" />`.

**Hence the questions:**

1. Can webpack also handle the server side files, but differently from the client side ones? I.e. transpile - yes, copy to dist - yes, bundle - no? Please, bear in mind I am using webpack-dev-server.
2. Is it possible to inherit tsconfig.json configuration so that I could avoid duplicating many options across the three files I have?
3. Is it possible to avoid the inclusion of `/// <reference path="../../typings/index.d.ts" />` in the top level TypeScript files when the file layout is similar to mine ?

I know these are three questions instead of one, but I feel they are all closely related and the answer to one could also be the answer to another.

Answer (score 1):

1. I don't think you need/want webpack to handle server-side files. Transpiling and copying over of the server side files to /dist is handled by Typescript compiler (via outDir config), already. There will be no bundling of server-side files since no server files were indicated as entry points in the webpack config.
2. Is not currently possible. However, looks like there is an issue to track this: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9876
3. Unsure, related to #3 in a way (but not really). I'd imagine no as long as you want to keep the client and server files truly seperate.